# drupal form textfield name -value changed and does not validate any more

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, textfield

i have a checkout-page (drupal commerce) form with an address section generated by the module addressfield. currently all text-inputfields have this markup-structure:

```
<input class="last-name" id="edit-last-name" name="customer_profile_billing[commerce_customer_address][und][0][last_name]">
```

class + id + name

with this config they validate.

if i change the value of the name attribute the form doesnt validate anymore, the form says:

> field XY is required

the form-validator obviously doesnt recognise my inputs.

question: how can i get the validation process to work with a modified name attribute?

Comment: But do you have to change the name of any input field? You can use your own validation function by altering the form.

Comment: "...You can use your own validation function by altering the form...." 
can you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: Check api.drupal.org for hook_form_alter

Answer (score 0):

You should not be altering the generated HTML in any way. Drupal provides a special way of handling forms and a special way to alter other modules forms. To change the form you should use the configuration options presented to you by the module. If those are insufficient you should [create your own Drupal module](https://drupal.org/node/361112) and then implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the other form. You will need to understand [Drupal's hook system](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-the-basic-concept-behind-hooks).